# How to split sums of array with separator?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I got an array from a single column from google sheet like `[[23.0], [25.0], [26.0], [89.0], [], [45.0], [78.0], [62.0], [], [123.0], [45.0], [68.0]]`
How can I split it with empty values `[]` and get sums for each sub-array like (`163/185/236`) or more, cuz array length may be more then 1000 including 20-50 empty values?
I modified script from the answer. But it doesn't work in my case. I don't understand why?

```js
function getSums(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('TemplateTest');
  var r = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow());
  var arr = r.getValues(); //log: [[23.0], [25.0], [26.0], [89.0], [], [45.0], [78.0], [62.0], [], [123.0], [45.0], [68.0]]
    var sums = [];
    var sum = 0;
    // iterate through the array
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
         if (arr[i].length == null || i == arr.length - 1) {
             // empty array, push sum to array and reset
             sums.push(sum);
             sum = 0;
         } else {
        // array has values, sum them up and add to sum
             sum += arr[i].reduce((a, b) => a + b);
         }
     }
    Logger.log(sums) //log: [16345786212345]
}
```

Where I'm wrong and how to fix it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [[23.0], [25.0], [26.0], [89.0], [], [45.0], [78.0], [62.0], [], [123.0], [45.0], [68.0]];
var sums = [];
var sum = 0;
// iterate through the array
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
    if (arr[i].length == 0 || i == arr.length - 1) {
        // empty array, push sum to array and reset
        sums.push(sum);
        sum = 0;
    } else {
        // array has values, sum them up and add to sum
        sum += arr[i].reduce((a, b) => a + b);
    }
}
```